# Escaping in yahoo pipes output (rss)

Tags: yahoo-pipes

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my [pipe](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pihentagy/kbcequitasreszveny)?

I am trying to make a hand build RSS from this webpage, and put the full html content of the links to the description tag. The output seems to be ok in the debug panel, but when I run this pipe, it returns empty result.

Comment: You should describe the problem as well as linking to a pipe, that way once the pipe is fixed the answer can still be useful.

Comment: @pguardiario True, will make a shot of my bogus pipe. Btw how can I make a shot, if it does not fit into the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to explain what I think is wrong.

- The first yql is good.
- The first loop is unnecessary
- The second loop's yql is a problem because it will give you an object
  instead of a string. You want the fetch page module instead.
- The final loop with the rss item builder, I believe you just want a
  'rename' instead of this.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful guide. Based on that, I corrected my pipe, which is here: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pihentagy/kbcequitas_rss

A question: `The second loop's yql is a problem because it will give you an object instead of a string`. Can I somehow get with YQL a string, instead of a html DOM? (for eq. if I need just some parts of the page, and the `cut content` filter settings were not enough?

Comment: About the first loop: I saw this technique in [this url](http://pipes.tigit.co.uk/?p=102), but it is really unnecessary (at least in my case)

Comment: I think there might be a way to get the string from yql with custom datatables but it's much more complicated than fetch page